# Post preview on blog displays all images

Tags: html, image, post, blogger, preview

Post preview on blog displays all images in the post. I'm on Blogger. Is there a code I can add to an image that will prevent it from appearing in the post preview on my home page?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To make it easier for other users to help you, please include some code to show [what you have tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com), preferably in the form of a [mcve]. See also [ask].